# PHP Chaining methods

Tags: php, methods, chaining

```
class AAA

{

    function getRealValue($var)
    {
        $this->var = $var;
        return $this;
    }

    function asString()
    {
        return (string) $this->var;
    }

}

$a = new AAA;
$a->getRealValue(30); 
$a->getRealValue(30)->asString();
```

So when i call $a->getRealValue(30) it should return 30,

but when i call $a->getRealValue(30)->asString() it should return '30' as string'.

Thank you

Answer (score 6):

> So when i call $a->getRealValue(30) it should return 30,but when i call $a->getRealValue(30)->asString() it should return '30' as string'.

This is not possible ([yet](https://github.com/nikic/scalar_objects)). When `getRealValue` returns a scalar value, you cannot call methods on it.

Apart from that, your class makes little sense to me. Your method is called `getRealValue` but it accepts an argument and *sets* the value. So it should be called `setRealValue`. Method chaining aside, could it be are you looking for a ValueObject?

```
class Numeric
{
    private $value;

    public function __construct($numericValue)
    {
        if (false === is_numeric($numericValue)) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException('Value must be numeric');
        }
        $this->value = $numericValue;
    }

    public function getValue()
    {
        return $this->value;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return (string) $this->getValue();
    }
}

$fortyTwo = new Numeric(42);
$integer = $fortyTwo->getValue(); // 42
echo $fortyTwo; // "42"
```

Comment: Actually his getRealValue returns this, which is an object. The problem is not with the ->asString() call, that works. The problem is with the getRealValue() which does not return an int but an object.

Comment: @HugoDelsing My initial statement is not referring to his actual code but rather the quoted passage.

Comment: Yes thanks.Basicly for example I want to get some value from some array, but after that i want to change the type as string or others.

Comment: @user2086527 there is usually very little need for that as PHP will typejuggle your code in a context sensitive manner anyways. That is, if you use an integer in a string context, PHP will figure that out without you having to explicitly cast the string.

Comment: Yes but that is only to show you an example.
There will be other methods that are comples like:
So that is NOT POSSIBLE:

$a->get('username'); // return 'john'
$a->get('username')->getHash(); // return 'y692mrth..'

???

Comment: @user2086527 it's only possible when get('username') returns an object with the getHash method. It is not possible when get('username') returns a string.

Answer (score 3):

Its not true, $a->getRealValue(30) will return object $a not value. But asString will return value in string format.

Usually when you want to get something like this you do:

```
$a->getRealValue(30)->get();
//Or
$a->getRealValue(30)->getAsString();
```

Comment: Basicly I want to get some value from some array, but I want to change the value as string for example.

// this will get me the id

$a->get('id')

So the beautier code will be something like this:

$a->get('id')->asString(); // its cool first i get the id after that convert it understandable!!!

It is not possible so what is the best solution:

$a->afterConvert('string')->get('id');
This will work but it's not semanticly good. It is not so understandable.

Any suggestions?